# Modifying section, subsection based on scope?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, ieeetran, grouping

Using MS Word 2013 I mocked up what I would like to create using LaTeX:

[image: MS word simulation]

I tried exporting it in LibreOffice using its [writer2latex](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/writer2latex-1); but that didn't work.

So starting from the [sectionbox](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sectionbox) LaTeX package, I wrote this:

```
\begin{sectionbox}{Title}
    \subsection{Description}
    \subsection{Design}
    \subsection{Tasks}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item
    \end{itemize}
\end{sectionbox}
```

Without modifying how `section`, `subsection` and `subsubsection` are treated everywhere else (using IEEE template), how do I get this to work?

Comment: Do you really need to use the sectioning commands? Also, is that all you want to appear inside your `sectionbox`?

Comment: That is all I want to include. Underneath each section will be paragraphs of text and items in the list will be populated of course also.

Comment: But these will be short (vertically) boxes, and wouldn't require page breaking (I assume)... Also, since you're using a journal class, are you limited in terms of other packages you may/not use?

Comment: I feel like I might be missing something really obvious, but isn't this rather standard use of [`titlesec`](http://http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `titlesec` you can redefine how sections and subsections are formatted:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%% use `titlesec` package to redefine how sections and subsections are formatted
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\huge\sffamily}{}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\sffamily\slshape\large\color{RoyalPurple}}{}{0pt}{}
\usepackage{sectionbox}
\definecolor{sectboxfillcol}{named}{White}
%%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{sectionbox}{Title}

    \subsection{Description}

    \lipsum[1]

    \subsection{Design}

    \subsection{Tasks}

\end{sectionbox}

\section{Title}

\subsection{Description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But you'll notice that this has a universal effect.  Perhaps that's the effect you want; perhaps this doesn't matter.  Per your comment about using IEEE template, this is probably not the route you want to go.

## To avoid effecting IEEE template:

But if it does matter, you can also create a new environment:

```
\documentclass{IEEEconf}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%% use `titlesec` package to redefine how sections and subsections are formatted
\usepackage{titlesec}
%%
\usepackage{sectionbox}
\definecolor{sectboxfillcol}{named}{White}
%%
\newenvironment{mysectionbox}[1]{%
    %\begingroup%
    \titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\huge\sffamily}{}{0pt}{}%
    \titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\sffamily\slshape\large\color{RoyalPurple}}{}{0pt}{}%
    \begin{sectionbox}{#1}
    }{%
    \end{sectionbox}%
    %\endgroup%
    }
%%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{mysectionbox}{Title}

    \subsection{Description}

    \lipsum[1]

    \subsection{Design}

    \subsection{Tasks}

\end{mysectionbox}

\section{Title}

\subsection{Description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This way your sectioning within the boxes can be formatted differently from those outside of the boxes.